# How to put string into string after specific string

Tags: objective-c

I am new in programming. I have string `NSString *string = @"\U0420\U043e\U0437\U044b";` and after each slash`('\')` i need put another slash to get string like this `@"\\U0420\\U043e\\U0437\\U044b"`

I am new to programming and objective-c. please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want as those strings are the same?

Comment: excuse me, I just corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original answer was:

Use `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a)).

```
NSString *string = @"\U0420\U043e\U0437\U044b";
NSString *converted = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" 
                                                        withString:@"\\\\\\"];
```

However I now don't think that's right given the `\` characters won't actually exist in `string`; instead the compiler will convert each of those sequences into a unicode character.  You will need to encode `string` as this:

```
NSString *string = @"\\U0420\\U043e\\U0437\\U044b";
```

In order to use the above code.  I cannot see any alternative to this.

**Further Update**: Often when I've come across questions like this there is a confusion between string literals and string data.  In your question those `\` characters won't appear as the compiler will have converted them into unicode characters (`\Uxxx` is a unicode escape sequence for a single character).  However if you provided a string like that at runtime (say read from a text file) then those `\` characters will exist and you can use the code above.

Comment: but i can't do this because json gives me it as "\U0420\U043e\U0437\U044b" and i need to convert in to russian letters. i tried to convert it with [NSString
                       stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                       encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding] but this method takes string as "\\U0420\\U043e\\U0437\\U044b" (with double slash)

Comment: @Asike How are you verifying what JSON gives you that string?  If those slash characters actually exist in the string then you will need to do more than simply adding slashes. I also doubt whether `stringWithCString` will do what you want.

Comment: it seems that I need to do something with NSJSONSerialization, but anyway thank you